# RoR: ActiveRecord.friendly.find() causes redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm supporting an application on RoR. One part of it I don't understand.
There is a model:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :prefix, :use => [:finders]
...
end
```

If I call Country.find("value") or Country.friendly.find("value") with value that doesn't exist in the database the call causes HTTP 302 immediately. If I change it to Country.find_by(prefix: "value") it works as expected except it returns nil for not found values.

Documentation says .find() should raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception. But it doesn't happen in my case.

I'm pretty new in RoR, so probably I've missed something obvious. Will be appreciated if you show me the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as you said `find` raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if the record with the given id is not found, where `find_by` just returns `nil` if the record with the given attribute(s) is not found.

That said, I think you have a `rescue_from` call, or something similar, in your application somewhere, maybe `ApplicationController`, which redirects when a `RecordNotFound` is catched.